# laravel route not found on live server

Tags: php, laravel, server

My laravel  app work in localhost 
but when I try to deploy on Shared hosting without ssh 
my route app not work, just '/' URL is work but when I call any route it returns 
**'Not found' 
"the request URL/myappName/Middleware/routeName was not found on this server"**

and I moved public content to root folder 
and changed directory for "vendor and bootstrap"

Comment: URL/index.php/login is it working please check..

Comment: thanks, I check it but it works

Answer (score 0):

Kindly read through this:

1. Make sure the Version of php on the shared hosting is higher or equal to the version of php your laravel is using.
2. After uploading the files, got to the public folder and move all the files in it to the root directory. then, go to index.php and find the following lines

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
and 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

modify the by removing /.. from each so that they look like the lines below

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Then check the url again.

Comment: I already changed my public file
and I tried it on localhost  and works correctly

Comment: localhost php version =7.2.11
but server php version =7.2.30
could it cause the problem??

Comment: but my laravel require php:^7.2.5

Comment: on the shared hosting, try changing the php versions as you reload the page. Hoping you have edited the lines above in the index.php file